# How to filter label name after count_values in promql

Tags: prometheus, promql

[image]

a gauge named bag_status with label(a)

using

```
count_values ("bag_status" ,bag_status)
```

it will count number for diferent values

I want to filter bag_status with value <1

```
(count_values ("bag_status" ,bag_status)){bag_status!=1}
```

does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go about it the other way around. Just filter for the values you want before applying `count_values`:

```
count_values("bag_status", bag_status < 1)
```